# How to use Captcha in Play Framework 2.1.3

Tags: playframework, captcha, recaptcha

I'm writing a blog engine in Play Framework 2.1.3 and for the comments I would like to use captcha or something like that to avoid automatic spams. I found some help about captcha, but that's only for Play 1.x and it doesn't work for me. Please give some help about how to get working the captcha in Play 2.1.3. Thanks!

Comment: Please describe your attempts, some code or what captcha technology you want to use.

Comment: I don't really now, because I haven't used any captcha technology yet. I just want to solve that when somebody write a comment on my blog, he'll need to confirm that he is a human. I want to avoid spam comments from scripts/robots on my blog. So, I'm open for any idea what helps to achieve this.

Answer (score 7):

I did try Google's recaptcha, it worked but it's horrible(It's very hard to read).

I implemented a simple solution using Java in Play framework 2.2.1.

1. Download [Kaptcha](https://code.google.com/p/kaptcha/) which is an opensource captcha package.Put it in the lib folder.
2. Implement a captcha method in *Application.java*.

   ```
   public static Result captcha(){
       DefaultKaptcha captchaPro=new DefaultKaptcha();
       captchaPro.setConfig(new Config(new Properties()));
       String text=captchaPro.createText();
       Logger.debug("Captcha:"+text);//U can put the text in cache.
       BufferedImage img=captchaPro.createImage(text);
       ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       try{
           ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", baos);
           baos.flush();
       }catch(IOException e){
           Logger.debug(e.getMessage());
       }
       return ok(baos.toByteArray()).as("image/jpg");
   }
   ```
3. Add the route to the *routes* file. Access http://[yourhost]:[port]/captcha .

```
GET     /captcha                    controllers.Application.captcha
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a [Google's recaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) for an example, you can even find a [short tutorial](http://techminded.net/blog/adding-captcha-in-playframework2.html) how to implement this (note: I didn't check its validity)

Comment: Actually this is working, so thank you! But it's using scala and I rather use java. It does the captcha validation in the ReCaptcha.scala in /app/views. I think this is not the best practice, it would be better to do the validation in the Application.java. I'm just don't now how to change the code for that. I also found a plugin at [github](https://github.com/fradev/play2-recaptcha) what may do the work, but it doesn't work. Somebody used this plugin or know some other plugin like this for Play 2.1.x?