# Generating Captcha code in play framework with scala

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, captcha

I want to generate Captcha code in play framework with scala.
Please tell me how to solve this problem, I am not able to find the Image.captcha in my  `play.libs._` package.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are talking about `play.libs.Images` which is relevant for Play framework 1.x only. Play framework 2.x has no built in captcha-generating mechanism so you should use some external captcha generators.

Consider reading this post: [How to use Captcha in Play Framework 2.1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18550107/how-to-use-captcha-in-play-framework-2-1-3)